# Cordova (Android Plugin) - Send data from Main Activity to InAppBrowser

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, socketmobile

I am using the Socket Mobile Capture SDK, which provides an easy method for receiving data from bluetooth connected barcode scanners assuming you can add a method to an android Activity class.

Below is the MainActivity code I have created.  The onData method correctly fires each time an external bluetooth scanner is used.  I would like to forward this information to the inAppBrowser.  Is this possible or is there a better way to do this?

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // enable Cordova apps to be started in the background
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean("cdvStartInBackground", false)) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }

        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);

        Capture.builder(getApplicationContext())
        .enableLogging(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        .build();        
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onData(DataEvent event) {
        System.out.println("onData fired from MainActivity");
        DeviceClient device = event.getDevice();
        String data = event.getData().getString();
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Here is my code from index.js which sets up the InAppBrowser:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {        
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        alert('device ready');

        var url = environment == 'Development' ? developmentUrl : productionUrl;        
        inAppBrowserRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no'); //open the in app browser with no location bar
        inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener( "loadstop", function() { //Fired when browser is finished loading
            alert('inappbrowser loaded');          
        });        
    },    
    // Once the InAppBrowser finishes loading
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work by using loadUrl("javascript:onData(\""+data+"\")").  Below are the changes I made:

Modify MainActivity.java onData method to:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onData(DataEvent event) {
    DeviceClient device = event.getDevice();
    String data = event.getData().getString();           
    loadUrl("javascript:onData(\""+data+"\")");
}
```

Add this function to my index.js file:

```
function onData(data) {
    inAppBrowserRef && inAppBrowserRef.executeScript({ code: "onData(\""+data+"\")" 
}); // Clear out the command in localStorage for subsequent opens.
}
```

Comment: what libraries are you importing to get this to work? I am getting a compilation error on "loadUrl" cannot find symbol